# C++ object lifetime and destructors called

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

I'm trying to understand object lifetime in C++. When I run the code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo &old);
    ~Foo();
    int x_;
};

int nextX = 0;

Foo::Foo()
{
    cout << "Foo(): " << (x_ = nextX++) << endl;
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo &old)
{
    cout << "Foo(const Foo &old): " << (x_ = nextX++) << endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    cout << "~Foo(): "<< x_ << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    vector<Foo> v(1);
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    Foo bar;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;
    v[0]=bar;
    cout << "-----------------" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Foo(): 0
-----------------
Foo(): 1
-----------------
Foo(): 2
-----------------
-----------------
~Foo(): 2
~Foo(): 2
~Foo(): 0
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why the copy constructor is not called in the statement `v[0]=bar`?
2. Why the destructor for the object originally called bar is called twice (i.e. `~Foo(): 2` is seen twice on the output)?

Would anyone be able to help me, please?

Thank you

Comment: `v[0]=bar` is not copy construction, but assignment (which you have not overloaded). (And this is *soo much* a duplicate.)

Comment: First I would say that you're going to need to make "nextX" a static variable so that it doesn't get reset to 0 for each new object.  See what happens from there.

Comment: Polka Dancer nextX is not in the class so won't reset, it is global and static already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The assignment operator is called because the object at v[0] has already been constructed.  The automatic assignment operator will perform a shallow copy of all members which ...
2. Because of the shallow copy of the automatic assignment operator it will appear that the ~Foo(): 2 is seen twice since two objects contain the member _x with a value 2.

Answer (score 1):

At `v[0]=bar;` an implicitly defined *copy assignment operator* (`Foo &operator=(const Foo &);`) is called. It copies `x_` (2) from `bar` to `v[0]`. So, you see `2` when destructors of `bar` and `v[0]` are called.

Answer (score 0):

Try the assignment operator is being used and hence 2 appearing twice